# Cortar string quando chegar no caratere espaço

Tags: c#, .net, string

Exemplo:

Tenho uma *string* "João da Maquipe", como faço pra cortar no espaço, deixando como resultado: "João" ou "João ". tanto faz. Em PHP eu sei, mas em C# não tenho a menor ideia.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A solução do dcastro é boa mas eu prefiro assim:

```
var parte = texto.Substring(0, texto.IndexOf(' '));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AHn7H7). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPEyeC). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitOnSpace.cs).

Fiz uma comparação entre as duas formas e a minha tem otimização tornando muito rápido. A outra não só é bem mais lento neste cenário mas também consome tanta memória que eu só pude fazer 10 mil interações antes de ter um problema de memória. Além dela exigir o uso do LINQ que tem seu lugar, só não é neste.

Não quer dizer que ela não seja válida e não possa ser usada sem problemas em alguns cenários, mas a que eu postei é muito mais simples. E é mais próximo do que é feito em outras linguagens que o AP está aprendendo também. É mais legível para a maioria das pessoas.

Answer (score 14):

Usa [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) para separar a string numa colecção de strings separadas por um espaço. E depois usa [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) para obter o primeiro elemento dessa colecção, ou `null` se a colecção for vazia.

```
var first = str.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```