# Removendo parte de uma string - C#

Tags: c#, string

Como eu posso remover os meus últimos caracteres de uma string ate chegar a um determinado caractere?
Por exemplo:

string url = "www.google.com.br/teste";

Eu precisava remover a palava teste até chegar no caractere "/". Gostaria de jogar o restante em outra variável, ficando apenas assim:

string resultado = "www.google.com.br";

Isso é possível?
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção é usar o [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string url = "www.google.com.br/teste";
string resultado = url.Split('/')[0];
```

Ou melhor que isso, usar o [Substring](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82070/cortar-string-quando-chegar-no-caratere-espa%C3%A7o?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
string resultado = url.Substring(0,url.IndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo, era exatamente isso que eu precisava!
Só vou aguardar 5 min restante pra aprovar sua resposta..
Obrigado!